# Is there a Dart Linter rule to force return type and method params for fields?

Tags: dart

I'd like to make sure that this code can't exist in the codebase:
`final Function onPress` instead it should have to be `final void Function() onPress`

I have the following rules currently and can't seem to find the rule to get this picked up:

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
      - lib/**/*.g.dart
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
    
linter:
  rules:
    always-specify-types: true
    always_declare_return_types: true
```

Comment: I don't believe there is one. Though personally I'd just as soon do away with that convention too in favor of typedefs. (That one in particular has an existing typedef in the Flutter framework called `VoidCallback`.)

Comment: Thanks. I find typedefs generally just hinder readability, but we do use existing ones when they are clear, like VoidCallback.

Comment: I think defining a variable with a typedef is a lot more readable than e.g. `final Future<Map<String, U>> Function<T, U>(List<List<T>>, int, int, bool) listConfigurator;`

Comment: Me too, so I'd probably use it in that case. On the otherhand a typedef for `bool Function()` or `void Function(bool)` seems almost completely pointless and just adds coupling/boilerplate for no reason at all. And these types of simple handlers tend to be about 95% of what I define when its' not VoidCallback.

Comment: You use a descriptive typedef for the same reason you use a descriptive name for a variable: it gives a clear description of what the function is going to be used for instead of a generic function signature. And I would hardly call one line of code that is mostly comprised of a function signature you have to type out anyway an excessive amount of boilerplate, in fact I would argue that it's more boilerplate to manually type out the signature every time. (And typedefs are just matchers for function signatures not types in their own right, so I wouldn't call it coupling either.)

Comment: Well I would call it boilerplate when reading, as it must be declared outside the class and requires a code jump to view it. And declaring typedefs is much more akin to declaring custom variable type names on the fly, that we can all guess at what they are. I would much prefer to see `bool Function()` vanilla code, than try and guess at whatever random name the developer has come up with.

Maybe if there were better naming conventions around them like, BoolReturnCallback it would be better, but 90% of the time they are just called SomeRandomClassNameBuilder.

Comment: fwiw, it's actually recommended not to use typedef's with Dart2:
https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_private_typedef_functions.html
"in most cases, users want to see what the function type actually is right where it’s used, and the function type syntax gives them that clarity."

Comment: I don't know what you were trying to link, but you linked to the linter rule of prohibiting _private_ funcdefs, which I would agree are largely pointless.

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-inline-function-types-over-typedefs

Comment: `It may still be worth defining a typedef if the function type is particularly long or frequently used.`

Comment: Right, so just as I've been describing the entire time: in rare and specific cases maybe they "still" makes sense, but generally they do nothing but hinder readability.

Comment: The cases aren't that rare and specific. That sentence lays it out: function types that are long or frequently used. Just like ***I*** have been saying this whole time.

Comment: At any rate, this debate has gotten academic and pointless. The linter rule you are looking for doesn't exist. If you think it should, take it up with the Dart development team.